# Swift 1.2 StringLiteralConvertable error

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I recently updated to Xcode 6.3 with Swift 1.2, and received over 300 errors, most of which involved adding an exclamation point.  One type of issue that will not go away, however, is the error that "'_' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertable'".  This appears multiple times, in these situations:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("modifyUser", withParameters: ["objectId":user.objectId, "key":"won", "value":won as AnyObject],block:nil)

PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("modifyUser", withParameters: ["objectId":friend.objectId, "key":"parties", "value":played], block:nil)

PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("modifyUser", withParameters: ["objectId":creator.objectId, "key":"left", "value" :left], block: {
            (error) in
            self.remainingPotatos = PFUser.currentUser()["left"] as! Int
        })
```

The error appears to be on the strings that are the keys of the dictionary, however, they are by definition StringLiteralConvertable.  What gives?

UPDATE

This appears to be another case of Xcode detecting an error but not telling which one.  After adding '!' after 'objectId', the error switched to being about the data type of the arguments.  The error message is:

```
Cannot invoke 'callFunctionInBackground' with an argument list of type '(String, withParameters:NSDictionary, block(_)->(_)'
```

Which part is the problem? (Also, changing error to 'error:NSError?' gives a similar result.

UPDATE

Looking at the Parse documentation, the block signature should be

```
^(id result, NSError *error)
```

I tried changing the block to

```
{
(result, error) in
//code
}
```

But still receive the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with Xcode detecting the wrong error at the wrong place.  Adding an '!' after "currentUser()" fixed the problem, and the lines with nil blocks lost their errors with a clean.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the only problem, but you appear to have a key in one of your dictionaries of `"value"!` which isn’t valid in 1.2 (and would have compiled, but not made much sense, in 1.1)

```
import Foundation
let left = "blah" as NSString
let dict = ["value"!:left]
```

results in `error: '_' is not convertible to StringLiteralConvertible`

Comment: Sorry that was the result of me trying to fix the error.